# 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and am trying to create a new project set up. I tried installing the TypeScript as local to the folder and not global as recommended in the official website.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

my directory structure

[image]

Error

[image]

Looking for help on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install Typescript?
Try `npm install -g typescript`

EDIT

Sorry didn't read you question in detail. To install it locally, you should add it to your package json first: `npm install --save-dev typescript`

Then you sould find it in int the `node_modules/.bin` folder. Yo can run it like this: `node_modules/.bin/tsc`

If you want to manually install it, i.e. download the binaries (Not recommended) make sure you put the binaries in a PATH location. E.g. `c:\windows` (Totally not recommended)